# Default rsize and wsize for nfs v3

Tags: nfs

The /etc/fstab entry used by my nfs client is 
{server_ip}:/home/{server_user}/{server_path} /home/{client_user}/{client_path}

I wanted to know the rsize and wsize values used by default. I wanted to try out some benchmarks with 
various values smaller and larger than the default values so that i can arrive at an optimum value for 
my read heavy setup.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't modify rsize and wsize. Recent NFS servers and clients will work out the best value for you and will probably do a better job than you would as well. :)

Answer (score 6):

If you are on a Linux box, take a look at /proc/mounts. You'll find the current value there. If you specify no value in /etc/fstab, that will be the default (or at least, a value that is considered sane by the system).

Answer (score 0):

These are the options we use most of the time

vers=3,tcp,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,timeo=600,hard,intr

Comment: but nobody explain why use that parameter, this is my default rsize and wsize from my workstation [root@worktux ~]# grep nfs /proc/mounts
192.168.122.191:/nfsshare/export /mnt nfs rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=131072,wsize=131072,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=192.168.122.191,mountvers=3,mountport=20048,mountproto=udp,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.122.191 0 0

Answer (score -2):

I believe the default `rsize` and `wsize` are 8192 for both UDP and TCP mounts.

Comment: This isn't the case on recent distributions.